# Dynamic ScalarStyle to certain nodes with snakeyaml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, snakeyaml

I need to parse a complex payload into a yaml with double quoted or plain scalar style depending on the node of the payload

The result I would like to get is something like that:

`

```
config:
  zzh: true
  zzh-special-config:
    expressions:
    - expression: "(#{deliveryCity} IN ['MADRID', 'BARNA'] && (#{channel} IN ['1'] || (#{domain} IN ['core'] && (#{environment} IN ['des,test'] || #{layer} IN ['composite']))))"
      value: false
      description: "my-description"
```

`

If I use the following configuration:

`

```
public static Yaml getYamlMapper() {
final LoaderOptions loaderOptions = new LoaderOptions();
loaderOptions.setAllowDuplicateKeys(false);
loaderOptions.setMaxAliasesForCollections(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
loaderOptions.setAllowRecursiveKeys(true);

final DumperOptions dumperOptions = new DumperOptions();
dumperOptions.setIndent(2);
dumperOptions.setPrettyFlow(true);
dumperOptions.setDefaultFlowStyle(FlowStyle.BLOCK);
dumperOptions.setSplitLines(false);
dumperOptions.setDefaultScalarStyle(ScalarStyle.PLAIN);
return new Yaml(new Constructor(), new Representer(), dumperOptions, loaderOptions, new Resolver());
}
```

`

The expression is not correclty parsed:
`

```
config:
  zzh: true
  zzh-special-config:
    expressions:
    - expression: '(#{deliveryCity} IN [''MADRID'', ''BARNA''] && (#{channel} IN [''1''] || (#{domain} IN [''core''] && (#{environment} IN [''des,test''] || #{layer} IN [''composite'']))))'
      value: false
      description: my-description
```

`

However if I change the Yaml configuration in this way:

`

```
dumperOptions.setDefaultScalarStyle(ScalarStyle.DOUBLE_QUOTED);
```

`

The boolean and integer values breaks down (e.g.: `!!bool "true"`).... And it put double quotes also in the keys :/

`

```
"config":
  "zzh": !!bool "true"
  "zzh-special-config":
    "expressions":
    - "expression": "(#{deliveryCity} IN ['MADRID', 'BARNA'] && (#{channel} IN ['1'] || (#{domain} IN ['core'] && (#{environment} IN ['des,test'] || #{layer} IN ['composite']))))"
      "value": !!bool "false"
      "description": "my-description"
```

`

As you can see when I fix something other thing is broken... Therefore the ideal situation would be to do only in all `expression` nodes (e.g: config.zzh-amiga-config.expressions[].expression)

I thnk I could use the `ScalarNode` object but I don't see how to achieve my purpose especially considering that the list of expressions could appear under any node so some kind of wildcard would have to be used...

Could anybody help me please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe it would be enough if I know how to force double quotes on string params instead of singke quotes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I think this code do the trick I was looking for:

```
  public static Yaml getYamlMapper() {
    final LoaderOptions loaderOptions = new LoaderOptions();
    loaderOptions.setAllowDuplicateKeys(false);
    loaderOptions.setMaxAliasesForCollections(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    loaderOptions.setAllowRecursiveKeys(true);

    final DumperOptions dumperOptions = new DumperOptions();
    dumperOptions.setIndent(2);
    dumperOptions.setPrettyFlow(true);
    dumperOptions.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
    dumperOptions.setSplitLines(false);

    return new Yaml(new Constructor(), new ComplexDataExpressionRepresenter(), dumperOptions, loaderOptions, new Resolver());
  }

  /**
   * Special representer able to deal with expressions.
   */
  static class ComplexDataExpressionRepresenter extends Representer {

    public ComplexDataExpressionRepresenter() {
      this.representers.put(String.class, new RepresentQuotedString());
    }

    private class RepresentQuotedString implements Represent {

      public Node representData(final Object data) {
        final String valueToString = data.toString();
        if (valueToString.contains("#{")) {
          // This do the trick to expressions and maybe also to another properties but is ok.
          return ComplexDataExpressionRepresenter.this.representScalar(Tag.STR, valueToString, ScalarStyle.DOUBLE_QUOTED);
        }
        return ComplexDataExpressionRepresenter.this.representScalar(Tag.STR, valueToString, ScalarStyle.PLAIN);
      }
    }
  }
```

Best regards!